# Need explanation: Custom built function raises KeyError: 0

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

I am new to Python and need your help to resolve my problem

I have written below function to get the accuracy of my model

```
def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x]== predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0
```

But when I am passing the values to this function as below:

```
getAccuracy(y_test , y_pred)
```

I am getting the following error message: `KeyError: 0`

```
type(y_predict): 
numpy.ndarray

type(y_test)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Please help me!

Thanks,
Anupam

Comment: The problem that you have is that in your function you assume that passed variables are lists (or tuples) but I'm pretty sure it is a dictionary (at least one of them)
Could you print out `y_test` and `y_pred` and see their types? (additionally you could update the question with those variables)

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, you want to do `predictions.iloc[x]` instead of `predictions[x]`.